# How to add a Headrest to this chair?

Tags: comfort, office-supplies, furniture

I have this chair:

[image]

Here's me sitting on the chair:

[image]

Pardon the pixelated face :)

So, my question is how do I add a headrest to this chair?

My neck starts hurting after long time sitting on the chair. So I need a headrest.

Comment: This looks like an office in a company, as opposed to a home office. If your company focuses on ergonomics at all, you may be able to convince them to replace your chair with one that has a headrest.

Comment: Have you tried a standing desk?  Your neck is probably hurting from leaning forward so much throughout the day.

Comment: It's likely some other ergonomics issue is at play. Send us a picture of your posture when seated and working rather than looking at the camera. To me most of the setup looks wrong in terms of heights and angles

Comment: According to your snapshot, you are not in an optimal physical position. First, correct your office equipment for **ergonomic best practices**. You should not be slumped forward resting on your forearms, etc. There's more… Don't forget 20-20-20 — every twenty minutes, look at something twenty feet away, for twenty seconds. There's more… Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

So I agree with the comment that getting the right chair through your company may be the best and easiest option.

But not every company supports that and we are all about hacks here anyways :-)

Here is my hack...   the first challenge I see is the top of your chair has a curvature that bends away from the chair. That makes it particularly difficult to add just a straight bar with headrest because by the time your head reaches the head rest you will be looking up at the ceiling!

Second issue is the size of the frame with the mesh. There is not a lot to grab on to, and I'm going to presume that you wont want to permanently change the office chair so that it can be returned in it's original condition.

The headrest you will need will have to extend forward. I don't have measurements of the chair so I'm just guesstimating from looking at the image.

https://www.officesupply.com/office-furniture/chairs-chair-mats-accessories/chair-accessories/headrest/lorell-back-chair-mesh-headrest/p502656.html?request_type=mlt

[image: Headrest]

If you are lucky,, this will just snap on..  what are the chances? And what about if you need to change the position? In that case, I would use the existing base, and use clamps such as

[image: clamps]

To help with adjustment (clamp twist faces away from chair). There is a good chance that you may have to modify the plastic on the base of the headrest to allow for movement and clamp positioning, in that case a little cutting tool

[image: cutting tool]

will help shave off some of the plastic to allow more movement, but be careful not to remove too much material and make sure the clamp still has enough to hold on to. The clamp I'm guessing will need to be torqued down quite a bit so the headrest doesn't move every time you use it.

Priced it out for about a $35 hack. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

For no sew, quick-fix:

- get a large piece of fabric (before investing rehearse this with a bed sheet)
- get a pillow or two - this is your stuffing so accommodate to fit your needs
- lay the pillows on the chair in such a way as to comfort your back
- use the fabric (bed sheet) to secure the pillows in place to the back of the chair
  *You can tweak to achieve a pretty look (ex finish by tying the back of the fabric in a bow) *
  I used this method to beautify a ugly chair but this technique will hold your extra padding in place as well. Easy to wash too - just untie! Hope this helps :)

[image]
[image: I added the fabric for beauty effects but it will also hold pillows in place and allows you to take it off and wash it]

Answer (score 0):

Buy a section of PVC and a couple of elbows. Cut 2 pieces as tall as you want the headrest and add 4 inches. Slit those 2 sections 4 inches on each end. Attach the elbows and cut a piece to fit the gap. Now take a piece of plywood about 8x6 and add foam puzzle mat to it, add any additional padding you want, staple on some black fabric to the back and then glue a piece of MDF or a flooring sample to the back to cover the stapling and screw the whole thing together. It should just slip on thru the slits and then you can screw it if you want. You could also make it fit perfectly to the chair by heating the ends over the stove and holding it tight over the chair with a towel.

Answer (score 0):

You can buy both attachable backrest and headrest.

[image: Sold by aliexpress]If that is too pricey pick a tall broken chair on ebay or from garbage and fasten backrest from there to you chair with belts. If it comes with headrest then you are lucky if not then make sure to get a backrest which is easier to mod.

If the whole construction is too ugly, you can also buy a stretchable case cover.

Answer (score -1):

As far as we can search in google for such a product, no such add-ons have been released for this purpose. Moreover, you will not resort to enhancing your office chair by purchasing extra repair parts and adding them especially for you. Finally, this problem can be resolved using another hack possible, describing them as follows:

- Adjust your sitting position as shown in below picture.
  If you do as follows, chances for getting neck hurt will be very much less and thus the main problem gets resolved.

[image: seating position]

- Even then if you have neck pain, you could relax in the chair that you have as shown below, but in this case, you can not guarantee your health issue to be solved.

[image]

Comment: That second image is precisely what I (and probably OP) are trying to avoid. Look at the bending of his lower back, how much pressure is on his tail bone, and how little pressure is on his legs.